# jquery append creates two div elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to add div element to another div, via jquery but it creates two divs

```
$('div.col-direction').append('<div id="newset"></div>');
```

Comment: What do you mean by `creates two divs`? You created a div and append to another one, what's the problem?

Comment: what do you want the end result to look like? What your doing here makes sense that it would create 2 divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is occurring because the function is binded twice with the handler it can be removed by jQuery.unbind() method.
see [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

suppose u are writing on click of button-id "btn"

then instead of

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    $('div.col-direction').first().append('<div id="newset"></div>');
});
```

*use*

```
x=$("#btn");
x.unbind('click');
x.click(function(){
    $('div.col-direction').first().append('<div id="newset"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but what are you on about? Although this _may_ be the cause of the problem the OP is having, it's unlikely and you shouldn't make this large an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You append to a class here and not a div so if you have 2 div of that class, it will crate in both divs

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.col-direction').first().append('<div id="newset"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem. Removing closing tag helped for me.

E.g.:

```
$('div.col-direction').append('<div id="newset">');
```

But I've appended option to select by id, so I'm not sure that it works in your case.

E.g. (by id):

```
$('#location_list_location_ids').append($("<option>").attr('value', 6).text('Sixth location'))
```